# Do I need to update the path when installing a module?

Tags: python-2.7, module, installation

So I'm trying to install a module, specifically xlutils.   I've read through the resources that I've linked at the bottom, but none of those resources have allowed me to successfully install and import the module.  I'm running Windows 8 and using Python 2.7.

I downloaded the .tar.gz file containing xlutils, and unpacked it to `C:\Python` which was then a .tar file, so I unpacked that to the same folder.  This created a folder, `xlutils`, which looked like it contained what I need.  I also read somewhere that these should be stored in site-packages, so I moved it there.

But when I run import commands, they don't work, just tell me the module couldn't be found.  When I look at the path browser, it doesn't see the folder, but I'm certain it's in there.  That leads me to wonder, do I need to do something to manually update what the path browser can view?

Note that I've also already tried going to the command line, navigating to the folder containing the module, and typing `python setup.py install` but that just tells me that the term "python" is not found.  In general, my command line always does this though.  Usually I have to type `.\python` instead to run Python from the command line, but I also tried doing that here (i.e navigating to the folder and typing `.\python setup.py install` but it still says the same thing).

Also note that I can import numpy and scipy just fine, and I can see them in the path browser--not sure why those work while this one doesn't.

Resources I've already read but hasn't solved my problem:

(... Well, I tried providing the resources I've already viewed, but can't so many links with such low reputation.  But basically, I've read the first ten links on a Google search and two or three past Stack questions and answers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions I see:

- You can use the absolute path `C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install`
- You can [add the Python directory `C:\Python27\` to your path variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) before running `python setup.py install`

Comment: Sweet!  Totally worked, will upvote when I get the reputation to.  
(Note to any future readers:  To do this, I had to install the setuptools module first, but luckily I had already downloaded that trying to follow one of the already existing resources on the web.  But if you navigate to that folder and type the command User gave, it will install.  With that installed, you can navigate to any other module's folder and again type the command, and then it will also install.)